# What is the correct URL to reach this Web API endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i'm working with an API that i didn't made and there's no documentation about it, i have this class and method

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SearchController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("[action]")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<int> someMethod([FromQuery] QueryObject query)
    {
        //some logic
    }
```

and this is my query object

```
public QueryObject
{
    public int id {get; set;}
}
```

but i can't get to the breakpoint in the controller, i'm not quite sure how the url is suppose to be

Comment: the url should be: /api/Search/action

Comment: There's a *lot* of documentation on [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing). It's not new either, it was available in ASP.NET MVC too. What URL did you use? If it doesn't match the pattern, you won't be able to call the action.

Comment: In this case though, you specified that the `someMethod` action will be mapped to a route ending in `/action`. I suspet that's a typo?

Comment: yeah it was a typo haha i just edited the question

Comment: GET on {baseUrl}/api/Search?id=2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Make a get request to: {the API's base url}/api/Search/{method name}

Answer (score 1):

if u chose the mvc api project so it works with actions methods.

For example ...api/[controllername]/action_method

Other things are just classic C#

Answer (score -1):

My bad, i'm kind of new to API, i haven't used before the Route("[action]")

so the correct url was localhost:0000/api/search/someMethod?id=1